# Calculate average time for each specific user

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Suppose I have an array of object as:

```
const ReadingTime = [
    {
        "user": "john",
        "readingPeriod": 8681
    },
    {
        "user": "john",
        "readingPeriod": 8867
    },
    {
        "user": "naresh",
        "readingPeriod": 22321
    },
    {
        "user": "Samul",
        "readingPeriod": 1212
    },
    {
        "user": "Samul",
        "readingPeriod": 1221
    }
]
```

I want to calculate average time for each user and generate the output as:

```
{"john":8774,"naresh":22321,"Samuel":121.6}
```

I tried doing as:

```
let avgReadingTime = ReadingTime.filter(RT => RT.user == "john")
                                .map(el => ({ "processingTime": el.readingPeriod }));
```

and it gives reading for user john only, as [8681,8867].

But this is a really long process, I want to calculate for dynamic user, user adds dynamically and we can have average reading time for each user.

Please do let me know if anyone needs any further details. I'm still trying to figure out, will update my question according if something comes up.

**Edit: Previously my accepted answer is incorrect. As the solution provided not giving an average. Sorry for accepting without being thorough.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method of an array.

```js
const ReadingTime = [
  {
    user: "john",
    readingPeriod: 8681,
  },
  {
    user: "john",
    readingPeriod: 8867,
  },
  {
    user: "naresh",
    readingPeriod: 22321,
  },
  {
    user: "Samul",
    readingPeriod: 1212,
  },
  {
    user: "Samul",
    readingPeriod: 1221,
  },
];

const result = ReadingTime.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const { user, readingPeriod } = curr;
  acc[user] = acc[user] ? (acc[user] + readingPeriod) / 2 : readingPeriod;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```
ReadingTime.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  if (prev[curr.user]) {
    return {
            ...prev,
            [curr.user]: (prev[curr.user] + curr.readingPeriod) / 2,
        };
    }

  return {
        ...prev,
        [curr.user]: curr.readingPeriod,
    };
}, {});
```

Comment: Isn't this a weighted average, giving higher weight to entries later in the array? I don't think that was intended by the OP... You should instead sum all numbers and then divide by length

Comment: No. @CherryDT is right.....I tried with uneven number and then I came to know this is not giving me average...could you please take a look again?